# Running Laravel 5 scheduler with Cron job on Mac gives me class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, macos, cron

I created a command, and create a scheduler to invoke that command. I could run it in command line like this `php /path/to/artisan schedule:run`; however, when I put this to cron job with this `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` gives me class not found error

> [2019-07-12 05:02:00] local.ERROR: Class 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime'
>   not found {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Class 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime' not found

Everything runs perfectly in shell, but got this error with cron. 
The application is based on Laravel 5, and I use valet to run the application.

Comment: Search for `UTCDateTime` in your Command files and make sure that you have imported the respective namespace.

Comment: Hi, that class should be imported correctly because if I ran the command from command line, I can get the correct response.